# Extract Combo Box text via confirmation button

Tags: powershell, combobox

Full disclosure, I am a novice at powershell. I have created a script that requires the user to select from a group of local users on the PC from a combobox in Powershell. I have also created a button to confirm said selection. My problem is that when the user clicks confirm I want that text in the combobox, not necessarily referring to the local user on the PC, to be represented by the $User variable. So, drop down menu, select user, click confirm, and now the rest of my script will run with the combobox text represented as $User.

For right now I have a textbox labeled $OutputBox to see if it is importing the combobox text; it is not needed. I have tried $Button.add_click{$DropdownBox.text = $User}), $DropdownBox.SelectedItem = $User, and a few other combinations that did not have the desired result. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400)

### At this point all the Assembly is a 600x400 pixel box. Next line creates the drop down menu, aka ComboBox in the .NET forms. 

$DropDownBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)
$DropDownBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20)
$DropDownBox.Height = 400

$CancelBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelBtn.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,75)
$CancelBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(260,250)
$CancelBtn.add_click({$form.tag = $form.Close()})

$Details = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Directory -Exclude default*, ntsetup, thsystem, -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
foreach($Detail in $Details){
$DropDownBox.Items.Add($Detail)
$DropDownBox.Sorted = $true
}

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,100)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,50)
$Button.Text = "Confirm Selection"

$OutputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$OutputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.size(420,50)
$OutputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$OutputBox.Height = 100

$form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox)
$Form.Controls.Add($OutputBox)
$Form.controls.add($Button)
$form.controls.add($cancelbtn)

$Button.add_click({})

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You need to flip that assignment around: `$Button.add_click({$User = $DropDownBox.SelectedItem})` <-- this will assign the current value of `$DropDownBox.SelectedItem` (ie. the directory name) to `$User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this...

```
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400)

<#
At this point all the Assembly is a 600x400 pixel box. Next line creates the 
drop down menu, aka ComboBox in the .NET forms. 
#>

$DropDownBox           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownBox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)
$DropDownBox.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20)
$DropDownBox.Height    = 400

$CancelBtn                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelBtn.Text                 = 'Cancel'
$CancelBtn.Size                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,75)
$CancelBtn.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(260,250)
$CancelBtn.add_click({$form.tag = $form.Close()})

$Details = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Directory -Exclude default*, ntsetup, 
           thsystem, -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

foreach($Detail in $Details)
{
    $DropDownBox.Items.Add($Detail)
    $DropDownBox.Sorted = $true
}

$Button             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,100)
$Button.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,50)
$Button.Text        = 'Confirm Selection'

$OutputBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$OutputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.size(420,50)
$OutputBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$OutputBox.Height   = 100

$form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox)
$Form.Controls.Add($OutputBox)
$Form.controls.add($Button)
$form.controls.add($cancelbtn)

$Button.add_click({$OutputBox.Text = $DropDownBox.Text})

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I dont know why I havent done this combination but yes, it absolutely does work. First time trying buttons and learned a lot. Thanks for the help.